# Download dialog taking a very long time to load in ASP mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, download

I have an ASP.NET web application that, in part, allows a user to upload (and download) documents.  The upload isn't working very well either, but my download dialogs are having a serious issue and I have no clue why.

These files are stored on a share that is not on the same machine as the code.
I am attempting to send the download via a FilePathResult using the File overload File(location, mimetype, displayname).

When a user clicks the download link it will open a new blank page and begin the loading animation but will stick to this for a good couple of minutes for larger files (up to 25 mb) before showing the save/download dialog, where it then takes about 5 seconds to actually download the file.

I have hunted and hunted and so far the only thing I"ve found is that FilePathResult is supposed to not buffer the file in memory but instead simply hand over the file to the user for downloading.

Does anyone have any insight as to why it would take a good (timed) 5m 45s to bring up the download dialog on a file that is only 24 mb? I feel like IIS or asp is pre-loading the document somewhere when it shouldn't be, and even if it is that is way too much time for such a small file...

For reference:

```
        public FilePathResult DownloadFile(int id)
        {
            var file = _fileService.GetByIdForUser(id, base.LoggedInUserId);

            return File(file.Location, UploadedFileManager.DetermineContentTypeFrom(file.Extension), file.Name);
        }
```

Comment: Have you looked into authentication? It sounds like credential verification to me.

Comment: Did you measure the time taken by the `_fileService.GetByIdForUser` method call?

Comment: It takes no time to pull up any smaller files (under 1mb for instance) so I can't imagine it is a verification issue.

The service call is just a database call; It takes next to no time to pull up the record (this only stores a document description, ID, and user foreign key).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not much of a "fix", but I figured I should add this in-case anyone else has a similar problem.

It turns out that the people managing one of our network switches had some settings messed up and we had to submit a support ticket to have it fixed. Once this was done, everything worked fine.

Anyway, the issue was in the fact that they had our hardware running at "half-duplex" (1 way communication).  I'm no network guy, this is just what I was told was the issue. I hope if anyone else has this problem that this might remind them to check with their hardware settings.